# I'd like a non-piecewise function, like $\sin(x)$, but with flattened constant wave above the $x$-axis and higher frequency waves below the $x$-axis

Tags: trigonometry, piecewise-continuity

Long story short I'm basing a keyboard animation on the sin-wave, $f = \sin(x)$ where x is time and $f$ is the height of a given key on the keyboard.

With this model, at $x = \pi/2$ we reach a peak height of the key, and at $x = 3\pi/2$ we have the key at its lowest point. Hopefully this makes sense.

Clearly modeling the movement after the sine wave implies that the key is constantly moving. I would like my key to instead stay at it's highest point for sometime, say $\pi$ seconds then press down and come back up like the original sin-wave,returning to its highest position in $2\pi$ seconds but then stay at its highest point again for $\pi$ seconds before repeating.

I made a terrible drawing to show what I mean:
[desired curve for key movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuFwT.png)

Is there a way to write out this function without making a piecewise function? I know this is an odd question but I am just having fun with some of the trig functions I can use to animate. In case you're wondering I am using Cinema4D.

Comment: What's problematic about making it a piecewise function? There are various operators that could be used to describe this sort of behavior but without a clearer understanding of why you're looking for the particular constraints you want, it's hard to give something that's going to be helpful.

Comment: @steven thanks for your reply. Without getting too technical, the reason a piece wise in the traditional sense (separating functions based on domain) is not what I wanted is because I’m using a specific input parameter in my 3D software that doesn’t allow conditionals. My bad for not explaining that. Conditionals are one way to do it but I was looking for a more succinct way while still using this parameter that I’m exploring. The answer below used the min function which is a very simple way to keep everything in a single field/line and get piecewise behavior out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to math.se! Are you familiar with the min and max functions?

I would suggest using something like the following:
$$f(x)=\min\left(\pi\sin5\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
, which takes in some kind of sine curve and a line at $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$ (where you want the plateau to be) and plots the lowest value out of the two. So, the line will only show when the sine curve is sufficiently close to peaking.

It looks like this:

[image]

You can now manipulate it in whatever ways you choose! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Micah! This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for and now I have a better idea of what min and Max() are haha.